# Django-tinymce-filebrowser Browse button not working

Tags: django, tinymce

Hi Iam Using jquery TinyMce Editor in Django.

For Image upload, I tried Django-tinymce-filebrowser from https://github.com/aisayko/Django-tinymce-filebrowser in my project.

```
tinyMCE.init({
           ...
           file_browser_callback : "mce_filebrowser"
    });
```

In editor, Image url with browse button is displaying. But by clicking the browse button, nothing happens. Help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you get any javascript errors (in your console)?